# Finding all possible case permutations in Python

Tags: python, string, permutation, case-insensitive

I need to return a list of all possible **case** permutations of a string in python.

For example, input `"ar"` should return:

```
[ 'ar','Ar','aR','AR']
```

or `"arc"`:

```
[ 'arc','Arc','ARc','aRc','aRC','ARC']
```

Comment: What you're asking for is basically an algorithm, if you know the algorithm you can implement it in whatever language you want (Python). All i can help you with that is: recursion. (trying some things on paper may help)

Comment: @nekosune: Out of curiosity, what are you using this feature for? I'm concerned that maybe you're using this to compare a string of unknown case to see if it matches a word. If so, there are better ways to do that.

Comment: @Bryan No, if I was doing that would use tolower, I am using app engine and wish to return a query which is insensitive to case, using the in part of GQL to do such, as it is garenteed to be short words.

Comment: The easiest way would be `itertools.product(*zip(string.lower(), string.upper()))`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
def all_casings(input_string):
    if not input_string:
        yield ""
    else:
        first = input_string[:1]
        if first.lower() == first.upper():
            for sub_casing in all_casings(input_string[1:]):
                yield first + sub_casing
        else:
            for sub_casing in all_casings(input_string[1:]):
                yield first.lower() + sub_casing
                yield first.upper() + sub_casing
```

---

```
>>> [x for x in all_casings("foo")]
['foo', 'Foo', 'fOo', 'FOo', 'foO', 'FoO', 'fOO', 'FOO']
>>> list(all_casings("foo"))
['foo', 'Foo', 'fOo', 'FOo', 'foO', 'FoO', 'fOO', 'FOO']
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, this was perfect. Algorithms especially recursive have allways been my weak point.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  What's the point of comparing the uppercase/lowercase letter (as `'a'` should never equal `'A'`) and slicing the first character (versus `input_string[0]`)?

Comment: To avoid returning two results when there's a character without upper/lower distinction, e,g, `'.'.upper() == '.'.lower()`

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by [zipping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the upper and lower case letters and taking their cartesian [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools

chars = "abc"
results = list(map(''.join, itertools.product(*zip(chars.upper(), chars.lower()))))

print(results)
>>>['ABC', 'ABc', 'AbC', 'Abc', 'aBC', 'aBc', 'abC', 'abc']
```

---

To visualise how this works:

1. `zip` is creating our 3 'axes' for us, each with 2 points (the upper / lower cases):

   ```
   [('A', 'a'), 
    ('B', 'b'), 
    ('C', 'c')]
   ```
2. `product` takes the cartesian product of these axes, i.e. the 8 possible coordinates corresponding to the corners of the unit cube it creates:

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| 1. Create axes | 2. Take Cartesian product |

3. `''.join` concatenates the tuples to output a string: `('A','B','C') -> 'ABC'`

Comment: While this is a great idea, you need to be careful about characters whose upper and lower cases are the same (e.g. '7'). In which case you need something like: (''.join(prod) for prod in itertools.product(*((letter, letter.swapcase()) if letter != letter.swapcase() else (letter,) for letter in word)))