# Find all combinations (upper and lower and symbols) of a word in python

Tags: python, iteration, combinations

I hope it's Monday-itis kicking in at the moment, but something I feel *should* be quite easy - or at least elegant - is giving me a brain fart. The use case is this:

Find all possible combinations of a specific word, where letters can be any case or replaced with letters. For instance:

Word: 'Password'
Combinations: 'PASSWORD', 'P@ssw0rd', 'p@55w0rD' ...

I do not want to write 7 loops to find this out, even though it's a once off script we'll never ever use again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all upper, lower and mixed case combinations of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144389/find-all-upper-lower-and-mixed-case-combinations-of-a-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import itertools

places = [
    "Pp",
    "Aa@",
    "Ss5",
    "Ss5",
    "Ww",
    "Oo0",
    "Rr",
    "Dd",
]

for letters in itertools.product(*places):
    print "".join(letters)
```

If you need to handle arbitrary words, then you'll need to write code to create the `places` list from the string.

Comment: I had tried `itertools.product`, but didn't realise it could take several iterables. I knew it was this easy, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue with this problem, is that not all letters can be translated to symbols or numbers. You have to create a dictionary where the key is a lower case letter and the value is a list of all possible replacement of that letter:

{'a':['a','A','@'],...,'s':['s','S','5'],...,}

Once your dictionary is built, the rest is just a matter of a simple Cartesian product of the different lists in the right order.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
symbols = dict(a="@", s="5", o="0")  # char -> str
text = "password"
print list(itertools.product(*[[letter, letter.upper()] + list(symbols.get(letter, "")) for letter in text.lower()])
```

Answer (score 1):

[itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is what you're searching for:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from itertools import product

def getAllCombinations(password):
    leet = ["Aa@","Bb","Cc", "Dd","Ee","Ff","Gg","Hh","Ii","Jj","Kk",
            "Ll","Mm","Nn","Oo0","Pp","Qq","Rr","Ss5","Tt","Uu","Vv",
            "Ww","Xx","Yy","Zz"]

    getPlaces = lambda password: [leet[ord(el.upper()) - 65] for el in password]

    for letters in product(*getPlaces(password)):
        yield "".join(letters)

for el in getAllCombinations("Password"):
    print el
```

If you are curious what the [asterisk *](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk) means, here you are: [foggy on asterisk in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239856/foggy-on-asterisk-in-python)