# Duplicating each character for all permutations of a string

Tags: javascript, typescript, duplicates, permutation

This is a slightly odd/unique request. I am trying to achieve a result where e.g "yes" becomes, "yyes", "yees", "yess", "yyees", "yyess", "yyeess".

I have looked at this: [Find all lowercase and uppercase combinations of a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992204/find-all-lowercase-and-uppercase-combinations-of-a-string-in-javascript) which completes it for capitalisation, however my understanding is prohibiting me from manipulating this into character duplication (if this method is even possible to use in this way).

```
export function letterDuplication(level: number, input: string){

const houseLength = input.length;
if (level == 1){

    var resultsArray: string[] = [];
    const letters = input.split("");
    const permCount = 1 << input.length;


    for (let perm = 0; perm < permCount; perm++) {
        // Update the capitalization depending on the current permutation
        letters.reduce((perm, letter, i) => {
          
        if (perm & 1) {
        letters[i] = (letter.slice(0, perm) + letter.slice(perm-1, perm) + letter.slice(perm));
        } else {
        letters[i] = (letter.slice(0, perm - 1) + letter.slice(perm, perm) + letter.slice(perm))
        
      }
          return perm >> 1;
        }, perm);
        
        var result = letters.join("");
        console.log(result);
        resultsArray[perm] = result;

        

    }
```

If I haven't explained this particularly well please let me know and I'll clarify. I'm finding it quite the challenge!

Comment: You need to show more code of how you are thinking. But you could use a regex, and then a for loop to go through the results.

Comment: @Krullmizter I did link the other page containing the code I was basing it off of, but I've edited it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**General idea**
To get the list of all words we can get from ordered array of letters, we need to get all combinations of letters, passed 1 or 2 times into word, like:

```
word = 'sample'
array = 's'{1,2} + 'a'{1,2} + 'm'{1,2} + 'p'{1,2} + 'l'{1,2} + 'e'{1,2}
```

Amount of all possible words equal to `2 ^ word.length` (`8` for `"yes"`), so we can build binary table with 8 rows that represent all posible combinations just via convering numbers from 0 to 7 (from decimal to binary):

```
0 -> 000
1 -> 001
2 -> 010
3 -> 011
4 -> 100
5 -> 101
6 -> 110
7 -> 111
```

Each decimal we can use as pattern for new word, where `0` means letter must be used once, and `1` - letter must be used twice:

```
0 -> 000 -> yes
1 -> 001 -> yess
2 -> 010 -> yees
3 -> 011 -> yeess
4 -> 100 -> yyes
5 -> 101 -> yyess
6 -> 110 -> yyees
7 -> 111 -> yyeess
```

**Code**
So, your code representation may looks like this:

```js
// Initial word
const word = 'yes';
// List of all possible words
const result = [];

// Iterating (2 ^ word.length) times
for (let i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, word.length); i++) {
    // Get binary pattern for each word
    const bin = decToBin(i, word.length);
    // Make a new word from pattern ...
    let newWord = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        // ... by adding letter 1 or 2 times based on bin char value
        newWord += word[i].repeat(+bin[i] ? 2 : 1);
    }
    result.push(newWord);
}

// Print result (all possible words)
console.log(result);


// Method for decimal to binary convertion with leading zeroes
// (always returns string with length = len)
function decToBin(x, len) {
    let rem, bin = 0, i = 1;
    while (x != 0) {
        rem = x % 2;
        x = parseInt(x / 2);
        bin += rem * i;
        i = i * 10;
    }
    bin = bin.toString();
    return '0'.repeat(len - bin.length) + bin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example can help you. It's a bit not neat and not optimal, but it seems to work:

```js
function getCombinations(word = '') {
  const allCombination = [];
  const generate = (n, arr, i = 0) => {
    if (i === n) {
      return allCombination.push([...arr]);
    } else {
      arr[i] = 0;
      generate(n, arr, i + 1);
      arr[i] = 1;
      generate(n, arr, i + 1);
    }
  }
  generate(word.length, Array(word.length).fill(0));

  return allCombination.map((el) => {
    return el.map((isCopy, i) => isCopy ? word[i].repeat(2) : word[i]).join('')
  });
}

console.log(getCombinations('yes'));
console.log(getCombinations('cat'));
```