# Find all upper/lower/mixed combinations of a string

Tags: lua, permutation, uppercase, lowercase

I need this for a game server using Lua..

I would like to be able to save all combinations of a name 
into a string that can then be used with:

```
if exists (string)
```

example:

```
ABC_-123    
aBC_-123     
AbC_-123 
ABc_-123     
abC_-123
```

etc

in the game only numbers, letters and `_ -` . can be used as names.

```
(A_B-C, A-B.C, AB_8 ... etc)
```

I understand the logic I just don't know how to code it:D

```
0-Lower    
1-Upper
```

then

```
000    
001
```

etc

Comment: Do you really need to generate all such combinations, or do you just want to check whether a new string is present in all such combinations of another string? These are two different tasks with different solutions.

Comment: all combinations yeah

Comment: If you want to use it like `if exists (string)`, if I understand it correctly, you don't need all combinations. So which exactly is expected?

Comment: maybe i shouldnt have added the if exits comment, maybe its confusing...its hard to explain. "if mapingamefolder exists" is a function in that games mod.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific directory in case-insensitive way on a case-sensitive file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive generator. The first parameter contains left part of the string generated so far, and the second parameter is the remaining right part of the original string.

```
function combinations(s1, s2)
        if s2:len() > 0 then
                local c = s2:sub(1, 1)
                local l = c:lower()
                local u = c:upper()
                if l == u then
                        combinations(s1 .. c, s2:sub(2))
                else
                        combinations(s1 .. l, s2:sub(2))
                        combinations(s1 .. u, s2:sub(2))
                end
        else
                print(s1)
        end
end
```

So the function is called in this way.

```
combinations("", "ABC_-123")
```

You only have to store intermediate results instead of printing them.

Comment: That works :D Thx a lot. Now i only hope it wont lag too much in game.

Comment: Ok ill try to write in more detail but its too complicated for my brain:D So you have this game that has an unofficial server LUA mod. I added a racing timer to the server, people can send maps and so on and records are stored for each map now problem i get is that i can A block people from uploading maps or B somehow make it so that all maps that are sent to the server are treated as case-insensitive. There is only a linux version of the server so if the server has a map named RACE1 some player can send a map named rACE1 which will then share a score or be 2 separate maps which is not good.

Comment: What about storing these files with *normalized* names, e.g. in lowercase?

Comment: server doesnt allow me to act before the map is sent or to change its name:( Also problem is that users know the maps and their cases well and are also using auto completion when voting them example: MAp+tab will find the MAp01 on their system and vote it as that.

Comment: @sarin it's Lua, not LUA, Lua is not an acronym.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only in the `exists` function then you don't need all combinations.

```
local stored_string = "ABC_-123"

function exists(tested_string)
        return stored_string:lower() == tested_string:lower()
end
```

You simply compare the stored string and the tested string in case-insensitive way.

It can be easily tested:

```
assert(exists("abC_-123"))
assert(not exists("abd_-123"))
```

Comment: thx, but it really needs to be something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144389/find-all-upper-lower-and-mixed-case-combinations-of-a-string while normally passing the numbers and special characters or this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168181/get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-word-in-lower-uppercase-letters

Answer (score 0):

***How to do this?***

There's native function in Lua to generate all permutations of a string, but here are a few things that may prove useful.

---

***Substrings***

Probably the simplest solution, but also the least flexible. Rather than combinations, you can check if a substring exists within a given string.

```
if str:find(substr) then
    --code
end
```

If this solves your problem, I highly reccomend it.

---

***Get all permutations***

A more expensive, but still a working solution. This accomplishes nearly exactly what you asked.

```
function GetScrambles(str, tab2)
   local tab = {}
   for i = 1,#str do
      table.insert(tab, str:sub(i, i))
   end
   local tab2 = tab2 or {}
   local scrambles = {}
   for i = 0, Count(tab)-1 do
      local permutation = ""
      local a = Count(tab)
      for j = 1, #tab do
         tab2[j] = tab[j]
      end

      for j = #tab, 1, -1 do
         a = a / j
         b = math.floor((i/a)%j) + 1
         permutation = permutation .. tab2[b]
         tab2[b] = tab2[j]
      end
      table.insert(scrambles, permutation)
   end
   return scrambles
end
```

---

***What you asked***

Basically this would be exactly what you originally asked for. It's the same as the above code, except with every substring of the string.

```
function GetAllSubstrings(str)
    local substrings = {}
    for i = 1,#str do
        for ii = i,#str do
            substrings[#substrings+1]=str:sub(ii)
        end
    end
    return substrings
end
```

---

***Capitals***

You'd basically have to, with every permutation, make every possible combination of capitals with it.

This shouldn't be too difficult, I'm sure you can code it :)

---

***Are you joking?***

After this you should probably be wondering. Is all of this *really* necessary? It seems like a bit much!

The answer to this lies in what you are doing. Do you **really** need all the combinations of the given characters? I don't think so. You say you need it for case insensitivity in the comments... But did you know you could simply convert it into lower/upper case? It's very simple

```
local str = "hELlO"
print(str:lower())
print(str:upper())
```

This is HOW you should store names, otherwise you should leave it case sensitive.

---

***You decide***

Now YOU pick what you're going to do. Whichever direction you pick, I wish you the best of luck!