# Find all upper, lower and mixed case combinations of a string that contains numeric and special chars

Tags: python, string

I want to write a program that would take a string, let's say "abc", then it would display:

```
abc, Abc, ABc, ABC, AbC, aBc, aBC, AbC
```

After digging for a while I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144389/find-all-upper-lower-and-mixed-case-combinations-of-a-string) which solves my problem however, if the string contains some special chars such as `@` and `.` , it will give me some duplicates in the output , how can I make it so only alphabetic characters are upper/lower? for example if the input is `a@c` the output should only be:

```
A@c
a@C
A@C
a@c
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
import itertools

string = 'abc12@abc.com'
x = map(''.join, itertools.product(*((c.upper(), c.lower()) for c in string)))
print(x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Caius's answer works, but it's more efficient to remove the duplicate *characters* up front instead of waiting until you have all the results and then removing the duplicates there.

The difference in my code is just `set((c.upper(), c.lower()))` instead of just `(c.upper(), c.lower())`:

```
import itertools
string = 'abc12@abc.com'
x = map(''.join, itertools.product(*(set((c.upper(), c.lower())) for c in string)))
assert len(list(x)) == 512
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the array into a set:

```
x = set(map(''.join, itertools.product(*((c.upper(), c.lower()) for c in string))))
```