# Iterate to get case alternatives in python

Tags: python, list, permutation, case-sensitive

A really simple question:

```
word = 'toy'
```

I want to generate following:

```
word_altered_cases = ['toy', 'Toy', 'tOy', 'toY', 'TOy', 'tOY', 'ToY', 'TOY']
```

I went this far:

```
for char in word:
  word.replace(char, char.upper())
```

But obviously, it will produce incompelete permutation and will replace all chars present in word.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792803/finding-all-possible-case-permutations-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144389/python-string-with-upper-case-and-lower-case-combination

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> word = 'toy'
>>> [''.join(w) for w in itertools.product(*zip(word.lower(), word.upper()))]
['toy', 'toY', 'tOy', 'tOY', 'Toy', 'ToY', 'TOy', 'TOY']
```