# How can I send multiple Set-Cookie headers from API Gateway using a proxied Lambda

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, cookies, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm using API Gateway's Proxy integration to call a Lambda. The output format specification is this follow JSON format:

```
{
  "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
  "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
  "body": "..."
}
```

In one response I wish to set two cookies (two different auth cookies) but JSON doesn't allow having two identical keys in the `headers` object (OK, technically the spec does but most libraries do not).

[RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.2) notes that Set-Cookie should be handled specially but I can't see how I can send multiple Set-Cookie values through API gateway.

Does anyone know whether this is possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please note that in 09/2022 AWS Api Gateway by default uses a new payload format (version 2.0) that no longer recognizes `multiValueHeaders` as proposed by all the top answers, including the accepted answer. I just spent 40 minutes trying to figure out why it doesn't return my cookies :).

From AWS Documentation:

> Format 2.0 doesn't have multiValueHeaders or
> multiValueQueryStringParameters fields. Duplicate headers are combined
> with commas and included in the headers field. Duplicate query strings
> are combined with commas and included in the queryStringParameters
> field.
>
> Format 2.0 includes a new cookies field. All cookie headers in the
> request are combined with commas and added to the cookies field. In
> the response to the client, each cookie becomes a set-cookie header.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html

So the actual solution should now be:

```
    return {
      statusCode: 302,
      headers: {
        Location: location,
      },
      cookies: [
         "cookie1=value1;",
         "cookie2=value2;"
      ]
    };
```

Comment: Thanks @Samuel - I've accepted this and made a tweak to the top answer signposting this.

Comment: Best answer for current SDK version

Comment: Hello, I tried this out and it works for HTTP API, but I'm having trouble getting it to work for REST API. Do I have to add a Mapping Template specifically for "cookies"?

Answer (score 28):

**Note:** API gateway now has a version 2 payload that is fundamentally different from that described here (and the default for new APIs). Documentation on the differences [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html). See other [accepted answer from Samuel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73584829/3990127) for some more details.

As of November 2018 this is possible using the `multiValueHeaders` field in the response instead of `headers` (see [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/support-for-multi-value-parameters-in-amazon-api-gateway/)).

As an example instead of:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "testing multiple set-cookie headers",
  "headers": {
    "X-Test-Header": "baking experiment",
    "Set-Cookie": "cookie1=chocolate-chip",
    "Set-Cookie": "cookie2=oatmeal",
    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
  }
}
```

You can respond with:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "testing multiple set-cookie headers",
  "multiValueHeaders": {
    "X-Test-Header": ["baking experiment"],
    "Set-Cookie": ["cookie1=chocolate-chip", "cookie2=oatmeal"],
    "Content-Type": ["text/plain"]
  }
}
```

Note that you can use a mix of `headers` and `multiValueHeaders`:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "testing multiple set-cookie headers",
  "headers": {
    "X-Test-Header": "baking experiment",
    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
  },
  "multiValueHeaders": {
    "Set-Cookie": ["cookie1=chocolate-chip", "cookie2=oatmeal"]
  }
}
```

However using the same header in both will mean that the value under `headers` is dropped.

See the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format) for more details.

When using only the header field (as available prior to Nov 2018) I tried sending the following manually curated JSON as a response:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "testing multiple set-cookie headers",
  "headers": {
    "X-Test-Header": "baking experiment",
    "Set-Cookie": "cookie1=chocolate-chip",
    "Set-Cookie": "cookie2=oatmeal",
    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
  }
}
```

The cookies that API gateway returns in response to a CURL request are:

```
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 35
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Thu, 29 Sep 2016 11:22:09 GMT
< Set-Cookie: cookie2=oatmeal
< X-Test-Header: baking experiment
< X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
```

As you can see the first `Set-Cookie` is dropped on the floor.

Comment: @MarkB that is not true, [see rfc6265](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#page-7). You need to be able to respond with multiple `Set-Cookie` headers because each cookie could have different levels of cookie security, expirations, etc.

Comment: I think ideally AWS would instead utilize the [the `Headers` interface of the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers). A `Headers` instance allows you to `headers.append(key, value)` meaning that you can set the `Set-Cookie` header multiple times. Then you could invoke the Lambda callback with the `headers` property equal to either a plain object *or* a `Headers` instance.

Answer (score 8):

As answered, to date, API Gateway will drop identical keys, only setting one of the cookies.

However, a workaround exists. You can change the casing of the string `'Set-Cookie'` so the keys are not unique. For example, you could use the keys `set-cookie`, `Set-cookie`, `sEt-cookie`, and the headers will be preserved and 3 different cookies would be set.

Because the RFC standard makes headers [case-insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259004/5747944) this should work with all RFC-compliant clients.

So, you could rewrite your set-cookie headers, [permuting all the possible casings of "Set-Cookie"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6792898/5747944) to get around this.

This technique (hack) is [employed by Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/blob/master/zappa/middleware.py), a popular serverless framework written in Python.

Comment: Only just seen this and obviously now fixed properly, but whoever thought this hack up deserves a unicorn. Brilliant.  Thanks for bringing it to my attention @sytech

Answer (score 4):

Use multiValueHeaders:

```
response.multiValueHeaders = {
  "Set-Cookie": [
    'cookie1=value1',
    'cookie1=value1'
  ]
}
```

or:

```
{
    "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
    "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
    "multiValueHeaders": { "headerName": ["headerValue", "headerValue2",...], ... },
    "body": "..."
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format

Answer (score 3):

As Mark B pointed out, you can/should achieve this by setting multiple cookie name/value pairs in a single Set-Cookie header. The browser should interpret this correctly.

```
Cookie: a=1; b=2
```

Edit: as pointed out by OP, there are use cases that require multiple instances of the header. We've added it our backlog along with supporting multiple header names on incoming requests.

Comment: [See rfc6265](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#page-7). You need to be able to respond with multiple `Set-Cookie` headers because each cookie could have different levels of cookie security, expirations, etc.

Comment: I see, good point. I'll have to add this to our backlog; it may take a while if we have to change the shape coming back from Lambda and accept both formats.

Comment: The suggested `Set-Cookie` isn't a valid use of the header. You may only set one cookie per header (unlike `Cookie` sent from the browser, which works exactly as you say above). Everything after the first `;` is interpreted as options such as expiry, max-age etc. See the syntax in [the RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.1).

Comment: I've just tried this with Chrome. When Chrome receives a headers of `Set-Cookie": "cookie1=chocolate-chip; cookie2=oatmeal`, Chrome sets `cookie1=chocolate-chip` and discards the invalid attribute - which follows the RFC as far as I can tell.

Your update won't work at all - `Cookie` headers are sent form the browser to the server rather than from the server to the browser (sending all accumulated cookies back to the server on each method call).

Comment: @JackKohn-AWS, wouldn't it be as simple as allowing either a string (which is the current syntax) or an array of strings. Sounds backward compatible to me.

Comment: hi, what is the status of this now?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of years late, but I just required to implement something like this and this is how I was able to make it work:

```
...

//15 minutes
var expirationTime = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 15 * 60 * 1000);
//30 minutes
var expirationTime2 = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 30 * 60 * 1000);

var response = {};

var cookies = [];
cookies.push("testCookie={'keyX':'valx', 'keyy':'valy'}; Expires=" + expirationTime + ";");
cookies.push("testCookie2={'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}; Expires=" + expirationTime2 + ";");

response.headers["Set-Cookie"] =  cookies;

...
```

Each array item will be processed independently, so you can add as many cookies to the array with different settings.

i.e.

```
cookies.push("testCookie3={'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}; Expires=" + expirationTime2 + "; Max-Age=...");

cookies.push("testCookie4={'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}; Expires=" + expirationTime2 + "; Domain=<domain-value>; Path=<path-value>");
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who using API Gateway V2 you can send multiple cookies by using `cookies` prop.

```
// Make sure to import V2 types from aws-lambda pacakge
import { APIGatewayProxyEventV2, APIGatewayProxyResultV2 } from "aws-lambda";

export async function lambda(event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2> {
  return {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    cookies: ["cookie1=value", "cookie2=value"], // Provide cookies
    body: JSON.stringify("{ isAuthenticated: true }"),
    statusCode: 200,
  }
}
```