# Use multiple same header field in Lambda Proxy Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm writing a Lambda function that returns a response for [Lambda Proxy Integration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html) in Python. The [API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format) expects headers to be a dictionary.

```
{
    "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
    "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
    "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
    "body": "..."
}
```

This requires each header field to be unique, so there is no way to use multiple `Set-Cookie`'s.
I've already tried to convert the dictionary to a list of tuples

```
{
    "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
    "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
    "headers": [ ("headerName": "headerValue"), ... ],
    "body": "..."
}
```

but API gateway complains `Malformed Lambda proxy response`.

Any idea how to set headers with the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is currently not possible to send multiple cookies with lambda integration.

If you send multiple set-cookie, then it will take the last one. ok, such a junk implementation right.

Reference, [How can I send multiple Set-Cookie headers from API Gateway using a proxied Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39769222/how-can-i-send-multiple-set-cookie-headers-from-api-gateway-using-a-proxied-lamb)

Let us see other avaialable options,

**Lambda@Edge:**

Here is what I find working with Lambda@Edge,

You can create a lambda function for viewer response and modify the header to set cookies.

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
   const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
   const headers = response.headers;

   // send via a single header and split it into multiple set cookie here.
   headers['set-Cookie'] = 'cookie1';
   headers['Set-Cookie'] = 'cookie2';

   callback(null, response);
};
```

**API Gateway Integration Request mapping:**

Here is what I found and got working with integration request,

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your Lambda@Edge example is incorrect and will result in an error. Specifically, it is obsolete.  The data structures changed a few days before L@E became generally available.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot. Thanks for spotting the error if any. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html  still has the same example as it is in our production. I would like to change as well if something got changed. Can you point to the right documentation examples? I will fix the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

**Lambda@Edge:**

It is possible to set the headers this way:

```
response.headers['set-cookie'] = [
  { key: 'Set-Cookie', value: 'cookie1=value1' },
  { key: 'Set-Cookie', value: 'cookie2=value2' },
]
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html#lambda-event-structure-response

**API Gateway:**

Use multiValueHeaders:

```
response.multiValueHeaders = {
  "Set-Cookie": [
    'cookie1=value1',
    'cookie1=value1'
  ]
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format

Comment: I am getting error on using Lambda@Edge . Struggled a lot but was not able to resolve multiValueHeaders: {
              'www-authenticate': [{key: 'WWW-Authenticate', value:'Basic'}]
          }

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the multivalue example to work either.  I was inspired to write this instead:

```
// Lambda only allows one value per header, so to set multiple cookies
// we must set multiple case variations between "set-cookie" and "SET-COOKIE". 
// There are 512 combinations, which should be enough.
function AwsSetCookie(aws, cookie, count)
{
    let b = count.toString(2);
    if(b.length < 9) b = "0".repeat(9-b.length)+b
    const key = "set-cookie"
    let bp = 0;
    let kp = 0;
    let keyOut = "";
    while(kp < key.length)
    {
        let c = key.charAt(kp);
        if(c !== "-") {
            if(b.charAt(bp) === "1") c = c.toUpperCase();
            bp++;
        }
        keyOut += c;
        kp++;
    }
    aws.headers[keyOut] = cookie;
}
```