# How to return multiple cookies with AWS APIGateway and Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am trying to return two cookies from Lambda to client(Postman) via APIGateway.
I referred to the aws blog, and could return 1 cookie to client.

https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/compute/simply-serverless-using-aws-lambda-to-expose-custom-cookies-with-api-gateway/

But I have no idea to return 2 kind of cookies.
I tried like this, but not working.

```
return {
   'cookie': 'aaa=bbb; secure'               -> Okay, but just one cookie
    # 'cookie': 'aaa=bbb; ccc=ddd; secure'   -> ×
    # 'cookie': ['aaa=bbb','ccc=ddd']        -> ×
}
```

[image]
Could anyone give me an advise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I send multiple Set-Cookie headers from API Gateway using a proxied Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39769222/how-can-i-send-multiple-set-cookie-headers-from-api-gateway-using-a-proxied-lamb)

Answer (score 9):

As far as I can tell, you can't set multiple cookies in the same `Set-Cookie` header. There's literature on the internet saying that you can, but my attempts to replicate this in API Gateway were fruitless.

Additionally, at the time of writing, API Gateway doesn't allow you to set multiple `Set-Cookie` headers. [This has been a long-requested and still not implemented feature](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=205782).

If you can, I'd suggest packing all your information into a single object and sending the `JSON` in one cookie.

---

If you really need to though, here is a **disgusting** workaround...

API Gateway's response headers are case-sensitive, so you can define multiple instances of the `set-cookie` header by varying the case, like this:

```
Set-Cookie
SET-COOKIE
SeT-CoOkIe
```

Comment: I despise the case sensitive hack, but at the same time I can not stop laughing.

Answer (score 1):

With the Lambda function response for format `2.0`, as stated in the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html), to customize the response, your Lambda function should return a response with the following format.

```
{
    "cookies" : ["cookie1", "cookie2"],
    "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
    "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
    "headers": { "headername": "headervalue", ... },
    "body": "Hello from Lambda!"
}
```

Comment: Looks like you can use the `"cookies"` field on lambda responses instead of `Set-Cookie` headers. Much better than the current top answer of using case changing.

Answer (score 0):

Setup mapping with Response header Set-Cookie and mapping value “integration.response.multivalueheader.Set-Cookie”

source "https://medium.com/nirman-tech-blog/aws-gateway-api-endpoints-multi-value-cookie-mapping-a36586cebd5e"