# Keyboard input without upper and lower case discrimination in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create something like this:

```
answer = input("What's your name?")
if answer == "Mike":
    # code
if answer == "John":
    # code
else:
    # code
```

What I want to do is to write `Mike` or `MIKE` or `mIke` ... (and same with `John`) and make all of that cases `True`, but I don't know how to do that instead of using `answer.lower()`, `answer.upper()` ...

Comment: you can better use regex to compare names

Comment: [This could work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792803/finding-all-possible-case-permutations-in-python), then you will just have to check if the name is in the list

Comment: What's wrong with answer.lower() or answer.upper()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to re-invent the wheel, here you go:

```py
def is_upper(letter):
    return ord(letter) > 64 and ord(letter) < 91

def to_lower(word):
    lowered = ""
    for letter in list(word):
        if is_upper(letter):
            lowered += chr(ord(letter) + 32)
        else:
            lowered += letter
    return lowered

print(to_lower("MIKE"))
# >>> mike
print(to_lower("MikE"))
# >>> mike
print(to_lower("mIKe"))
# >>> mike
```

Answer (score 1):

How about do it manually by an easy list comprehension if don't use `.lower()` or `.upper()`?

```
def convert(s):
    return "".join(i if 65 <= ord(i) <= 90 else chr(ord(i) - 32) for i in s)


answer = input("What's your name?")
if convert(answer) == convert("Mike"):
    # code
```