# Function that yield or return all situation of small and Capital letters

Tags: python, function, yield, yield-return

Is there any function that  can take a "string" and yield all situation of small and Capital letters  every time i call function in a loop which is possible.for example:

> i give **"string"** to function

and it yield all of situation like:

```
"String"
"sTring"
"stRing"
"strIng"
"striNg"
"strinG"
"STring"
"StRing"
"StrIng"
"StriNg"
"StrinG"
...
```

I am new in python and i do not have any idea i though there might be a library or function that can do that.

Comment: Please check the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792803/finding-all-possible-case-permutations-in-python

Comment: Note that there are 2^N possibilities, where `N` is the length of the string - each additional character doubles the number of possibilities. This could get quite time-intensive for long strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding all possible case permutations in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792803/finding-all-possible-case-permutations-in-python)

Comment: @JeriesHaddad Nice find. For reference, don't forget that you're able to flag questions as duplicates in cases like this so that people can review it in the close vote queue.

Comment: thanks @JeriesHaddad, but this function is too slow when i give "my name is bob and 123456 is my number" and it can not dodge number and cuz error

Comment: It's slow because it has to produce an exponential number of values, not because it could be made more efficient.

Comment: this has to produce 2**24 (16777216) different results. Of course this is slow.
(24 is the number of letters in your string, which have to be permuted. white space and numbers are not counted)

Comment: it seems my answer is quiet close to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792803/finding-all-possible-case-permutations-in-python),but has some difference

Comment: *this function is too slow when i give "my name is bob and 123456 is my number"* This is exactly what I said in my comment - there are 2^N permutations, which is going to be extremely time-consuming for long strings.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica is there any way that this function does not make all possibilities and make them one by one then i use it if it didnt help me i use the next one???, so this will not cuz MemoryError

Comment: What's the criteria for when they help you or not? Iterating through 2^N items one at a time isn't going to be very time-effective. For a long string, that'll be like looking for a needle in a haystack. If anything, that'll probably be even worse than just generating all of them up front.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 'it can not dodge number and cuz error', there are two ways around it (Which you can modify the function to):

1. Add a try / except in each iteration as in:

> ```
> try:
>
> except:
>     continue
> ```

2. Check if the 'char' is a numeric value, using the **isnumeric()** function as in:

> ```
> > if char.isnumeric():
> >         continue
> ```

Comment: it seems i made a mistake this algorithm can dodge numbers and whitespace with this part `if first.lower() == first.upper():` this is always False for letter but True for others. any way it is steel slow i need do some thing that this function does not make all possibilities and make them one by one then i use it if it didn't help me i use the next one, so this will not cuz MemoryError